# Rails form_tag submit data without reload the whole page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, page-refresh

I have model called search for rendering data from database, Using index method I'm accessing data from 3 models, display it on index page.
I'm using form_tag in index page itself,

```
            <%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get", :remote => true, id: "search-form") do %>
            <label for="Longitude ">Lon</label>
              <%= text_field_tag :lng, params[:lng], :id => "longitude", placeholder: "Longitude" %>
            <label for="Latitude ">Lat</label>
              <%= text_field_tag :lat, params[:lat], :id => "latitude", placeholder: "Latitude" %>

              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" >Process</button>


        <% end %>
```

I haven't created any partial view for this.

I have added :remote => true in form_tag,I don't know where and how to call ajax for this?
I'm searching data from tables and getting updated data using '<%= escape_javascript @center_lat.to_json %>'; in index.html.erb file

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the form's remote option is set to true, the request will be posted to your controller as an Ajax request, looking for JavaScript. In order to serve that request, the action of your controller would look like this:

```
def MyController

  ...

  def my_action
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { ... }
      format.html { ... }
    end
  end
  ...
```

The `format.js {...` allows the controller to respond to your Ajax request. So you need to render a `.js` or a `.js.erb`.

Take a look here, it will be more enlightening: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: I have added format.js to my controller index action, created .js,erb  view but in that view How to render the index action?

Comment: Take a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns, you need to work with some javascript to render your results without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `:method => "get"` , to make a get request the page will always reload, try removing that and try to see if it works.

Also, your controller need to be able to answer to JS calls, make your the actions you are calling on your controller have something like this

```
respond_to do |f|
f.html { redirect_to tasks_url }
f.js
```

end

Comment: If I remove :method => "get" then it throws routing error, Because without get method it will consider post by default.

Comment: respond_to do |f|
f.html { redirect_to tasks_url } What is the tasks_url ?